# Node async method is not detecting results from iterator

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I'm trying to learn how to use the async method in my node js REST API.

**Goal**

I query the database for a range of keys... and loop through each one.  I check to see if any of the results match my current date / time stamp and if it does, I do a HGETALL query on the matching key. 
I'd like to send the results of the HGETALL as json data to the consumer of my REST API.

**Problem**

My code correctly queries the database for the initial set of keys... and then later for the HGETALL. 
But.. when I try to send the results back, nothing is currently displayed on the web page.

Here's the code:

```
var id_rule = function (redis_key, doneCallBack) {  
    console.log('iterator called with key:' + redis_key);
    //if this is the default rule, skip it  
    if (redis_key.indexOf('00:00_00:00') == -1){
        //time match
        var rule_times = parse_time_from_key(redis_key);
        var current = getCurrentUTC(); // returns something like [ 1158, 'mon' ]        
        if ( (current[0] >= rule_times[0] && current[0] <= rule_times[1]) && (rule_times[2].indexOf((current[1].substring(0,1))) != -1)) {
            var widgetkey = redis_key.split("widget:");             
            redis.hgetall("widget:" + widgetkey[1], function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("hgetall method fails: " + err);
                    return doneCallBack(err, false);
                }
                if (data) { 
                    console.log('bingo: ' + widgetkey[1] + "returned a match");
                    console.log(data);
                    return doneCallBack(false, data);
                } else { 
                    return doneCallBack(false, false);
                }                                       
            }); 
        } else {  
            return doneCallBack(false, false);
        }
    };
}

router.get('/:widgetnum', function(req, res, next) {
    //validate widgetnum format 
    var widgetnum = req.params.widgetnum;
    if ( !valid_e164(widgetnum) ) {
        var retval = {"res":false, "msg":"malformed widget"};
        res.send(JSON.stringify(retval));
    }
    console.log('scanning db for:  widget:' + widgetnum + "*");
    redis.send_command("SCAN", [0, "MATCH", "widget:" + widgetnum + "*", "COUNT","1000"], function (err, reply) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(JSON.stringify({"res":false,"msg":"no matching widget records found"}));
        }
        if (reply) {                    
            if (reply[1].length == 2) {
                //queryfordefault rule
                async.map(reply[1], queryhgetall_default_rule, function(err, results) {
                    console.log('inside here!');
                    res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
                });
            } else {
                async.map(reply[1], id_rule, function (err, iteration_results) {

                    if (err) {
                        res.send(JSON.stringify("false"));
                    }
                    if (iteration_results) {                    
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(iteration_results));
                    }                       
                });
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Line 37 is where I send my first query off to the redis database, and it returns an array of results.

Lines 49 - 56 is the async method that calls my iterator method ... once for each result in the result set.

Line 18 is where I'm trying to return data from the iterator back to the async method.

**Questions**

1. Clearly, I've messed something up with the way i'm returning my data so this would be my first question - can you see what I'm doing wrong.
2. How do I stop iterating through reply[1] (line 49)  once I've found what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

1. Post the code for queryhgetall_default_rule and id_rule also.  But first break all of that out into a different module and test that by itself without the HTTP request part of it.
2. See http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.some.

Also look into promises, Promise.any, and `await` (needs babel) with just a for loop doing one at at time.  Those are useful topics that take some time to learn.